# EWS: InvalidOperationException / ServiceResponseException

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have an EWS synchronizer that has stopped working at my company after some undos. It is not able to edit or update other employees mails and is saying privelege/rights to the calendar is missing. It was working 2 weeks ago, and nothing has changed in the code, I checked to see and the SID was changed, but i updated it and still gives me missing permission errors. I have not written this but am responsible for maintaining this synchronizer program, so excuse me if I sound a little in the dark.

**ServiceResponseException**:

```
else if (ex.InnerException is ServiceResponseException)
                                                                 {
                                                                     if (ex.InnerException.Message.ValueIn("The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.", "The specified folder could not be found in the store."))
                                                                     {
                                                                         a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.HasCalendarEditorPermission = false;
                                                                         a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(conn);

                                                                         Console.WriteLine("Rettigheder til kalender mangler for " + a.Initials);
                                                                         permissionEx.Add(a.Initials);
                                                                     }
```

**InvalidOperationException**:

```
} catch(Exception ex) {
                                                         if(ex.InnerException != null) {
                                                             if(ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException) {
                                                                 if(ex.InnerException.Message == "Agent has not assigned editor permissions") {
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.HasCalendarEditorPermission = false;
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(conn);

                                                                     Console.WriteLine("Rettigheder til kalender mangler for " + a.Initials);
                                                                     permissionEx.Add(a.Initials);
                                                                 } else
                                                                     exceptions.Add(ex.InnerException);
```

**HasCalendarEditorPermissions**:

```
private bool HasCalendarEditorPermissions(Folder calendar, string userSID) {
        if(calendar == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("calendar");

        if(calendar.GetLoadedPropertyDefinitions().Contains(FolderSchema.Permissions))
            SendExchangeRequest(() => calendar.Load(new PropertySet(FolderSchema.Permissions)));

        return calendar.Permissions.Any(p => p.UserId.SID == userSID &&
                                             p.DisplayPermissionLevel == FolderPermissionLevel.Editor);
    }
```

**Edit**:

```
    private Folder GetAgentCalendar(ExchangeService service, SAFEAgent agent) {
        string username = agent.EmailAddress;

        var calendar = SendExchangeRequest(() => Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, username)));

       // if(!HasCalendarEditorPermissions(calendar, SC01_SID))
         //   throw new InvalidOperationException("Agent has not assigned editor permissions");

        agent.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.HasCalendarEditorPermission = true;

        return calendar;
    }
```

Basically when i comment out the following, it runs my synchronizer again, but what has changed since this worked 2 weeks ago?

**Uncommented code that made program run again**

```
// if(!HasCalendarEditorPermissions(calendar, SC01_SID))
         //   throw new InvalidOperationException("Agent has not assigned editor permissions");
```

Comment: Its looks like its failing to bind to the Calendar folder so you need to look at the code that is actually bind to the Calendar Folder as that is what the error is indicating. The error is telling you that the email address being tried is either not the PrimarySMTP address of the mailbox in question or not a valid address. I'd suggest you look at the underlying EWS requests using something like fiddler

Comment: I found the method in which i bind the folder, and i uncommented some code and then it works again, but is it the WellKnownFolderName that is messing it up? I edited the code with the GetAgentCalendar() method

Comment: I'd suggest you do some testing with the ewseditor with the same account and you can compare that against what your app is doing using fiddler.